# Can I have an interlock hooked up to the single main breaker panel outside?

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker, generator

I’ve got a 150 amp main breaker (by itself) outside with a sub panel in the laundry room for every other breaker.

Can I add a 30 amp breaker for my generator to the main panel outside and then install an interlock to it? Is this something anyone has done or is it even possible?

[image]

[image]

I’ve got experience and tools from working and diagnosing car related electrical issues and I do know home voltage and amperage is much higher but just wanted a more experienced persons thoughts about this project. I have seen that you can add a main breaker to the sub panel and then add a generator breaker to it and do it that way but I think (if it’s possible) adding a breaker for the generator on the main then putting in that interlock on that same panel would be much less involved.

Comment: Add a picture of the main panel/breaker so we can see what is there.

Comment: Just added a pic of the panel and of the whole set up in case y’all need that too

Comment: Does the current main breaker panel has provision INSIDE for adding more breakers, breaker mounting hardware

Comment: Let's get a closer look at that breaker. Any chance you can post the photo instead of the thumbnail?  Pro tip, if the raw photo is too big to post, open it up in anything and save it again with JPEG quality of 3 (quality is a 1-10 or 1-12 scale). This dramatically shrinks the file in megabytes, but does not degrade resolution at all. (it adds a bunch of JPEG artifacts at the pixel level, but with so much resolution, who cares?)

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just use UL listed parts and install it according to labeling and instructions.  ***Oh, wait.***

I think you're asking "this thing was only built to be a main breaker and nothing else, can I **freestyle this** with random parts and metalwork?  Nope.

However, from what I can tell, this old thing doesn't owe you anything. And it's *just* a main breaker, so I would suggest swapping it for a "Ranch Panel" without meter pan - this has a main breaker, 4-8 breaker spaces, and "thru lugs" that go onward to your main subpanel.   Into 2 of the breaker spaces goes your generator interlock.

This is DIYable, but you'd need to have the power company "pull the meter" (typically done remotely using a big contactor inside the smart meter). Typically they'll want a permit and inspection, unless you can convince them that you're only exchanging the main breaker. (i.e. just install the Ranch Panel as a replacement for the main breaker, and then do the generator interlock another time).

Answer (score -1):

Can't do it with that panel. If your subpanel has a main breaker then you can do it there. If not then you'll have to change the subpanel from lugs to either main breaker (some are convertible) or a backfed breaker, or replace this outside panel. Replacing the outside panel will require a meter pull and likely permit and inspection.